# Width of the Progress Bar

Tags: php, html, css

My width of the progress bar is based in my formula itself, the problem is if the output was in 2 decimal places, you cant see the decimal and the % in the progress bar.

Here's my formula

```html
$p = number_format((float)($c/$t *100),2,'.','');
```

and here's my code for progress bar

```html
<td>
  <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='$p' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:$p%'>$p%</td>
```

Here's an image for better understanding

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the source code that is generated by PHP and sent to the browser (right click and select "Source")?

Comment: It looks like you're not actually echoing out the value into the width. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You aren't actually echoing out your width value, so it's not setting the width of the progress bar.

So change:

```
style='width:$p%'>
```

To:

```
style='width:<?php echo $p;?>%'>
```

Like this below:

```
<td>
<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='$p' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:<?php echo $p;?>%'><?php echo $p;?>%</div>
</td>
```